# modify text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<span class="one">
    <span class="two three">text</span>
</span>
```

i can't edit html. i can use only jquery. how can in this example delete class TWO and THREE and also modify text to: "new"

http://jsfiddle.net/MJaeV/

in my code is few class TWO. i must use for this class ONE

Comment: This is very basic jQuery. What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "delete class" you mean remove the classes, you can use [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$(".one .two").removeClass("two three").text("new");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/MJaeV/1/).

Comment: thanks, but in my code is few class TWO. i must use for this class ONE

Comment: I've changed the selector so now it will only apply to elements of class "two" which are descendants of elements with class "one".

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$('span.one span').removeClass('two').removeClass('three').text('new');
```

Or shorter:

```
$('span.one span').removeClass('two three').text('new');
```